# How to build simple neural network on keras (not image recognition)

Tags: neural-network, keras

I am new to keras and I am trying to built my own neural network.

A task:

I need to write a system that can make decisions for the character, which may meet one or more enemies. The system can be known:

- Percentage Health character
- Presence of the pistol;
- The number of enemies.

The answer must be in the form of one of the following:

1. Attack
2. Run
3. Hide (for a surprise attack)
4. To do nothing

To train up I made a table of "lessons":

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lD0WX.png

So here is my code:

```
# Create first network with Keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = numpy.array([[0.5,1,1], [0.9,1,2], [0.8,0,1], [0.3,1,1], [0.6,1,2], [0.4,0,1], [0.9,1,7], [0.5,1,4], [0.1,0,1], [0.6,1,0], [1,0,0]])
Y = numpy.array([[1],[1],[1],[2],[2],[2],[3],[3],[3],[4],[4]])
# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=3, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, init='uniform', activation='sigmoid'))
# Compile model
sgd = SGD(lr=0.001)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, nb_epoch=150)
# calculate predictions
predictions = model.predict(X)
# round predictions
rounded = [round(x) for x in predictions]
print(rounded)
```

Here the predictions I get.
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

The accuracy on each epoch is 0.2727 and the loss is decrease.
It's not right.

I was trying to devide learning rate by 10, changing activations and optimizers. Even data I input manually.
Can anyone tell me how to solve my simple problem. thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code.

1. Number of data entries are very small compared to the NN model.
2. Y is represented as classes number and not as class vector. A regression model can be learnt on this but its a poor design choice.
3. output of `softmax` function is always between 0-1 .. as this is used your model only knows to spew out values between 0-1.

Here below is a bit better modified code:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD
import numpy
# fix random seed for reproducibility
seed = 7
numpy.random.seed(seed)
# split into input (X) and output (Y) variables
X = numpy.array([[0.5,1,1], [0.9,1,2], [0.8,0,1], [0.3,1,1], [0.6,1,2], [0.4,0,1], [0.9,1,7], [0.5,1,4], [0.1,0,1], [0.6,1,0], [1,0,0]])
y = numpy.array([[1],[1],[1],[2],[2],[2],[3],[3],[3],[0],[0]])

from keras.utils import np_utils
Y = np_utils.to_categorical(y, 4)
# print Y

# create model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=3, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='softmax'))
# Compile model
# sgd = SGD(lr=0.1)
# model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=sgd, metrics=['accuracy'])
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['accuracy'])

# Fit the model
model.fit(X, Y, nb_epoch=700)

# calculate predictions
predictions = model.predict(X)

predictions_class = predictions.argmax(axis=-1)
print(predictions_class)
```

Note I have used the `softmax` activation as the classes are mutually exclusive